# Variável nao receber valor

Tags: c++, arduino

Tenho um programa, onde quando clico um botao o programa pausa, e ao clicar novamente ele continua, mas percebi que nesse periodo de tempo em que eu pauso o programa, a variavel que eu quero recebe valor mesmo estando em pause, como faço para ela não receber valor enquanto o programa esta em pause. Codigo:

```
  if (digitalRead(botao)==1){
   for(;;){
     if (digitalRead(botao)==1){
     goto programa;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Não tenho a certeza que vai funcionar, mas, tenta colocar um system("pause"):

```
if (digitalRead(botao)==1){
  for(;;){
    if (digitalRead(botao)==1){
    goto programa;
 }
}
//Se der erro na utilizacao do system("pause") mete a biblioteca -> stdlib.h
system("pause")
```